# android toggle button don't want to callback in setChecked()

Tags: android, android-listview

While developing an android app, I don't want to have a callback in `setChecked` method.
Instead I want to use a button with toggle for this purpose.

Below is my codes for this:
XXAdapter (ListView)

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    MHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = this.inflater.inflate(layout, null);

        holder = new MHolder();
        holder.toggleButton = (ToggleButton) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.my_toggle);
        holder.toggleButton
                .setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    MParam param = params.get(position);
    holder = (MHolder) convertView.getTag();

    ToggleButton toggle = holder.toggleButton;

    toggle.setChecked(false);
    if (param.state == 2)
        toggle.setChecked(true); // here
    return convertView;
}
```

How can I have the callback method on toggle button changed flag?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use this line if don't want action

```
holder.toggleButton
        .setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked `setOnCheckedChangeListener` for the `ToggleButton`

```
toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(arg1){
                    // toggleButton is checked
                }else{
                    // toggleButton is unchecked
                }
            }
        });
```